# Convert object into array object but reduce down by key name character number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, reduce

I have this object:

```
{
mainTitle: "xx",
press1: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press1imgs: [{…}, {…}]
press2: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press2imgs: [{…}, {…}]
press3: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press3imgs: [{…}, {…}]
press4: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press4imgs: [{…}, {…}]
press5: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press5imgs: [{…}, {…}]
press6: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"}
press6imgs: [{…}, {…}]
}
```

I'd like to reduce it down to an array but put all the `press1, press1imgs, press2, press2Imgs` in the same index. If the number after press is the same, put into the same index, so in total there'll be 6 indexes, to be like this:

```
[
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
{text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx", img: [{…}, {…}]},
]
```

I was able to convert the object into an array and get the number from `pressx`, but then I get lost into how to proceed, with reduce, filter, map? My attempt:

```
 const mapped = Object.keys(this.content).map((key) => ({
    key: key,
    value: this.content[key],
  }));

  console.log(mapped);
  mapped.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.key.charAt(5));
    if (item.key.charAt(5)){

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the keys are pretty dynamic, I'm doubtful that the array methods are a good choice here. I'd use a loop:

```
const input = this.content;
const results = [];
let i = 1;
while (input.hasOwnProperty('press' + i)) {
  results.push({
    ...input['press' + i],
    img: input['press' + i + 'imgs'],
  });
  i++;
}
```

Live snippet:

```js
const input = {
mainTitle: "xx",
press1: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press1imgs: [{}, {}],
press2: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press2imgs: [{}, {}],
press3: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press3imgs: [{}, {}],
press4: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press4imgs: [{}, {}],
press5: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press5imgs: [{}, {}],
press6: {text: "xx", linkUrl: "xx", linkText: "xx"},
press6imgs: [{}, {}]
}

const results = [];
let i = 1;
while (input.hasOwnProperty('press' + i)) {
  results.push({
    ...input['press' + i],
    img: input['press' + i + 'imgs'],
  });
  i++;
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: This works but the original object may not always return the keys in order, so I was hoping to use the charAt(5) method.

Comment: Even if the object is ordered with keys 5, then 1, then 3, then 4, then 2, it should work fine - the `i` in the code in the answer increments up from 1 regardless, and pushes keys that exist.